# WebView2 error: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: c#, webview, wix, windows-installer

On several client machines we constantly get this error:

`The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)`

The error happens when app tries render someting on a webview window. I don't know why client gets that error, the only way I am able to reporoduce the same problem on my machine is to delete `msedgewebview2.exe` file from `WebView2` folder of installed app.

I assume for some reason the file is missing on clinet side but I am not sure.

The file should be copied to that folder when app is installed. We use Wix script for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?define WebViewFolder = "$(var.SolutionDir)ExtDeps\WebView\" ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="WebView2" DiskId="3">
            <Component Id="cmp087AADB1F239327C35BD8DAF5622E9D0" Guid="*">
                <File Id="filF11293D6366A85FF459286B02E57F8A5" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebViewFolder)\100.0.1185.29.manifest" />
            <Component Id="cmp02770C0CD7F052952BDF325A39E1DE31" Guid="*">
                <File Id="fil5DCB5B24F4D8AA92A83D2C58A445DD0E" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebViewFolder)\msedgewebview2.exe" />                
   .....
```

The exception is thrown from here:

```
WebView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://internallocal.app");
```

Do you encounter the same problem. Can you hint what to do?

I suspect the reason could be the fact that we put `WebView2Loader.dll` on `runtimes\win-x64\native` folder but not on the same folder as exe. On one post I have read that it should be near the exe. Not sure which one is the correct place.

Comment: It may be a permission issue.  Does the same person install all the time with the same account?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) and [WebView2 Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues).

Comment: The WebView2 files in your in your installation folder need to remain in the same relative location that they are after the build process in the `bin\Release` folder.  You can see where they're placed by looking in the NuGet package .targets file: `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\<version>\build\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.targets` which has an import statement for `Common.targets` which has the information that you're interested in.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Using Visual studio installer project my build was working fine both on my machine and on the client's and for no apparent reason after a new install it started having this error on the client's machine while still working fine on mine. Tried to copy/replace the WebView2Loader.dll on the installation folder didn't make a difference. Checking the location of the dll I can confirm it is in the same relative location but still not working. I will update as soon as I have something new

Comment: Installing the [Evergreen bootstrapper](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section) worked for me, now trying to integrate the installation into the VS installer using these [instructions](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/main/SampleApps/WV2DeploymentVSInstallerSample/README.md). I hope this helps